# Unit Testing of parser method using pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocks

This is my first time using `pytest`. All feedback for this test case is much appreciated.

```
import pytest
from mock import mock_open, patch


def get_file_contents(file_data):
  with patch.object('builtins.open', mock_open(read_data=file_data)) as mock:
    with open('mocked_file') as f:
      return (line for line in f.readlines())


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def text_parser(request):
  from tparse import TextParser
  file_data = getattr(request.module, 'file_contents')
  tparse = TextParser(file_data)
  def fin():
    tparse.close()
  request.addfinalizer(fin)
  return tparse


def test_get_system_entry(self):
  file_data = 'dc nyc server server001 ipaddress 10.10.10.10'
  file_iterable = get_file_contents(file_data)
  assert file_iterable == file_data
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar using py.test, but here are some comments I have after reading your code:

1. There are no comments - this would be helpful to the reader.
2. In `text_parser`, you have `from tparse import TextParser`. I would advise moving this import to the top of the file, for readability.
3. What is your code trying to do with these tests? What are you testing?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Ryan. I was trying to follow the examples from py.test where it seems like including the imports in text fixtures is a pattern, however had I been performing traditional unit tests, I would have moved the imports to the top of the file. However, I am in agreement with you, and will most likely move the imports to the top of the file anyway. Currently I am testing a method that parses a string returned from an iterable. So basically open a file, read each line in the file, and the method will return the entry once the pattern is found.

Comment: Also, apologize for the lack of comments. Was trying to be descriptive in the code itself, however it will be something I keep in mind in the future so I can be respectful of ppls time. Thanks for taking the time to look at this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand this test:

> ```
> def test_get_system_entry(self):
>   file_data = 'dc nyc server server001 ipaddress 10.10.10.10'
>   file_iterable = get_file_contents(file_data)
>   assert file_iterable == file_data
> ```

The name of the test method suggests testing of getting "system entry".
Inside, I see a string (`file_data`),
and something that appears to be an iterable (`file_iterable`),
and a call to `get_file_contents`,
such that this expression is expected to be true:

> ```
> file_data == get_file_contents(file_data)
> ```

So, we test getting a system entry by verifying that `x == get_file_contents(x)` ?
I don't know what to make of that.

A good unit test case should be:

- perfectly clear
- easy to read and understand without deciphering
- have a good, descriptive name

And what is the `self` parameter for?
"self" is used as the first parameter of class methods.
But the `test_get_system_entry` method is not within a class,
and the parameter is not used anyway.
This is confusing code.